# kubeadm fails to init with timed out waiting for the condition

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I've set up a new server in digital ocean, ubuntu 16.04. installed docker from the ubuntu repos and set up kuberenetes according to this guide:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/

I've tried several times, to `kubeadm init` following by a `kubeadm reset` before trying again.

the output log suggests to check that `kubelet` is running and it does:

```
● kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
           └─10-kubeadm.conf
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-09-05 13:34:35 UTC; 24min ago
     Docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/home/
 Main PID: 2615 (kubelet)
    Tasks: 15
   Memory: 44.8M
      CPU: 3min 18.521s
   CGroup: /system.slice/kubelet.service
           └─2615 /usr/bin/kubelet --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml --cgroup-driver=cgroupfs --cni-bin

Sep 05 13:59:15 kubernetes-master kubelet[2615]: E0905 13:59:15.538370    2615 kubelet.go:2110] Container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin
Sep 05 13:59:17 kubernetes-master kubelet[2615]: E0905 13:59:17.518350    2615 kubelet_node_status.go:103] Unable to register node "kubernetes-master" with API server: Post https://48.88.103.0:6443/api/v1/nodes
Sep 05 13:59:18 kubernetes-master kubelet[2615]: E0905 13:59:18.552653    2615 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:455: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://48.88.103.0:6443/api/v1/ser
Sep 05 13:59:19 kubernetes-master kubelet[2615]: E0905 13:59:19.659689    2615 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:464: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://48.88.103.0:6443/api/v1/nodes?
Sep 05 13:59:20 kubernetes-master kubelet[2615]: W0905 13:59:20.556075    2615 cni.go:172] Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d
Sep 05 13:59:20 kubernetes-master kubelet[2615]: E0905 13:59:20.576691    2615 kubelet.go:2110] Container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin
Sep 05 13:59:21 kubernetes-master kubelet[2615]: E0905 13:59:21.952965    2615 certificate_manager.go:299] Failed while requesting a signed certificate from the master: cannot create certificate signing request:
Sep 05 13:59:23 kubernetes-master kubelet[2615]: E0905 13:59:23.817566    2615 eviction_manager.go:243] eviction manager: failed to get get summary stats: failed to get node info: node "kubernetes-master" not fo
Sep 05 13:59:24 kubernetes-master kubelet[2615]: I0905 13:59:24.524068    2615 kubelet_node_status.go:269] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
Sep 05 13:59:24 kubernetes-master kubelet[2615]: I0905 13:59:24.594325    2615 kubelet_node_status.go:79] Attempting to register node kubernetes-master
```

It also suggest to check network connectivity and that the images are able to download. I verified with pinging outside the network and checking that `kubeadm config images pull` executes successfully.

I do see that I get a `TLS handshake timeout` a lot in the journalctl log when it tries to reach the server's IP address.

I have seen a lot of discussion about this issue online but none of the existing solution has helped me this far.

What else can I test for/check/try?

Comment: Looks like there is not enough permissions for kubelet daemon. Try to check from what user does it run?

Comment: What makes you think it's a permission issue? It's running as root

Comment: As I can see in logs, kubelet cannot register services or even get acces to docker plugin